# emacs flyspell save word to file being checked

Tags: emacs, flyspell

In the past, I saved special words in the file being checked (as comments). I no longer can work out how to do this.

I remember there was an option when checking a word: add to global dictionary, add to local dictionary, add to file.

After doing this the word would not be marked as wrong, this persisted when the file was reopened in the future.

So **how do I save a spelling to the file being checked (as a comment)?**

Answer (score 1):

I am using Emacs 24.5.1 and it is still possible. When you check the spelling of the word under or before the cursor (using M-$ or function ispell-word), you have several options. Select option 'A' to accept the word and place it in a buffer local-dictionary. The latter means you will see the following comment line added to the end of you buffer:

```
#  LocalWords:  <yourword>
```

You can find all the options using "C-h f ispell-help".